# jquery .ajax() not firing with condition

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have put a condition before my jquery ajax() call, and it no longer fires. I basically only want the ajax() call the fire when someone hits enter in the text box.

The ajax() call works fine without the `$("[id$=txtSearch]").bind` condition.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to go about this?

```
$("[id$=txtSearch]").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});

$("[id$=txtSearch]").bind("enterKey", function (e) {
    var query = $("[id$=txtSearch]").val();
    alert(query); // This works 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Viewer.aspx/GetSearchResults",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ docID: docid, query: query, 
                      pageNumber: 1, resultsPerPage: 10 }),
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d.TotalResults);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                    alert("responseText=" + xhr.responseText + 
                           "\n textStatus=" + status + "\n 
                           errorThrown=" + error);
                }
            });
        });
```

And my text box:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" TextMode="Search" 
    AutoCompleteType="Search" placeholder="Search for text in the document..." 
    AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip="Search for text in the document..." >
 </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: can you share the input element html

Comment: try with `keydown` instead of `keyup`.

Comment: Key up isn't the issue. It works fine. The condition is working correctly since the alert(query) does get displayed. Its the ajax() call that is not firing when I have the condition.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the id for your selector.

Try using `$('#txtSearch')` instead of `$("[id$=txtSearch]")`

Comment: I tried that. For some reason it isn't working. I know that part is working anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your JS by

```
$(function(){
    $("#txtSearch").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).trigger("enterKey");
        }
    });

    $("#txtSearch").bind("enterKey", function (e) {
        var query = $("#txtSearch").val();
        alert(query); // This works 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Viewer.aspx/GetSearchResults",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ docID: docid, query: query, pageNumber: 1, resultsPerPage: 10 }),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d.TotalResults);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
                alert("responseText=" + xhr.responseText + "\n textStatus=" + status + "\n errorThrown=" + error);
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: $("[id$=txtSearch]") works fine. For some reason the other syntax does not. I don't think that is the issue as the alert(query) works after the condition. Its just the .ajax call that does not.

Comment: Does it works if you remove the line "data: JSON.stringify({ docID: docid, query: query, pageNumber: 1, resultsPerPage: 10 })," ?

Comment: The ajax call works fine without  $("#txtSearch").bind("enterKey", function (e) {.... before it.